# Set projection to a field that is an array is not working. ApostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to set a projection in order to retrieve less data from a query but the problem comes when I try to put inside the projection a field that is an `array`
This is my piece schema

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "attendee",
  extend: "apostrophe-pieces",
  alias: "attendees",
  label: "Attendee",
  pluralLabel: "Attendees",
  addFields: [
    {
      name: "_congress",
      label: "Congress this attendee has sign up for",
      type: "joinByOne",
      withType: "congress",
      filters: {
        projection: {
          _id: 1,
          title: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: "registrationDate",
      label: "Registration Date",
      type: "date"
    },
    {
      name: "registrationTime",
      label: "Registration Time",
      def: null,
      type: "time"
    },
    {
      name: "fields",
      label: "Fields",
      type: "array",
      titleField: "Array Label",
      schema: [
        {
          name: "name",
          type: "string",
          label: "String"
        },
        {
          name: "value",
          type: "string",
          label: "Value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

An my query is like this:

```
 return self.find(req, { congressId }).projection({ registrationDate: 1, registrationTime: 1, fields: 1 }).toArray();
```

When I put `fields: 1` I got this exception [image]

Otherwise returns the array as expected:

[image]

I also tried this query inside mongo shell and it worked:
`> db.aposDocs.find({_id: "ck35z61p400047e9e5ktt6wu4"}).projection( {fields: 1})`

`{ "_id" : "ck35z61p400047e9e5ktt6wu4", "fields" : [ { "id" : "attende1Field1", "name" : "name", "value" : "Name1" }, { "id" : "attendee1Field1", "name" : "lastName", "value" : "Last Name1" }, { "id" : "attendee1Field1", "name" : "treatment", "value" : "Treatment1" }, { "id" : "attendee1Field1", "name" : "email", "value" : "email1@email.com" } ] }` 
Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't quite add up somehow. Can you create a project in github that demonstrates the bug?

Comment: I opened a ticket in Github https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by a MongoDB bug, at least in the 2.x version of the MongoDB nodejs driver. It is specifically the field name `fields` that does not work and generates the error you saw:

```
Failed to parse: projection: 1. 'projection' field must be of BSON type object.
```

I renamed it to `fields2` and everything worked as expected. So your resolution is just to change the name of the array field. It would be interesting to see if this issue still occurs with the `apostrophe-mongo-3-driver` module configured.